# Unable to locate element in Python Using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

i have a problem with locating element with xPath.

```html
<li>
  <a aria-current="false" href="/drop"> 
    <button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; min-width: 88px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; border-radius: 2px; user-select: none; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: center; top: -7px;">
    <div>
      <span class="material-icons" color="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); position: relative; font-size: 18px; display: inline-block; user-select: none; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 12px; margin-right: 0px;">
        pin_drop
      </span>
      <span style="position: relative; padding-left: 8px; padding-right: 16px; vertical-align: middle; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; font-size: 14px;">Drop</span>
    </div>
    </button>
  </a>
</li>
```

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/nav/ul/li[7]/a/button/div/span[3]').click()
```

Hey, i tried using xPath and other method seemms it can't find this element.

Comment: Which span you are trying  to click ? Is it Drop or pin_drop?

Comment: if possible provide the link may be that can help

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to click on the Drop button then use the below xpath.

```
//li/a[@href="/drop"]//span[.='Drop']
```

[image]

Include below imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Your code should be:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/a[@href='/drop']//span[.='Drop']"))).click()
```

Comment: The above code will make sure the script will wait until the Drop  element is clickable.

Comment: Have you tried the code from my answer? If still you get NoSuchElement exception then you might have to check if the element is present in the iframe.

Comment: NameError: name 'driver' is not defined Still not getting to work Yeah i included everything still not working

Comment: I done it still not working NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Comment: Its no't in iframe

Comment: Are you getting 'NoSuchElment' exception when you run the script? Can you please paste the trace log here

Comment: And also check if the xpath works in chrome browser Elements window.

Comment: Tried `WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/a[@href='/drop']//span[.='Drop']"))).click()` and got error  `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element`
  `

Comment: It don't work in console but it works when using ChroPath Plugin it works tried using Xpath and CSS SELECTOR still no results

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li > a[href=/drop] > button span:nth-of-type(2)")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li/a[@href='/drop']/button//span[text()='Drop']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: @LukasAlišauskas Check out the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` Still i got error @DebanjanB When using xPath it shows no error but not working

Comment: @LukasAlišauskas _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.  Check the HTML and traverse upwards and observe if the element is within an <iframe> tag, then you have to switch to the desired `<iframe>` first before clicking the element. Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: Tried a lot of thing but still not wroking read full discuss still i got error there is no <iframe> When i trie to find element trough consolei `get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` But when i use ChroPath It finds elemnt and everything ok please help @supputuri

Comment: I found way to do it `driver.get('https://link/drop') ` like so but there is button and i can't click it same problem